# Отображать окно с маршрутами на яндекс карте

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Нужно чтобы на сайте, на карте, отображалось стандартное окно с построением маршрутов, как на скрине. Подскажите, как его активировать. Также нужно чтобы оно работало, т.е. при вводе адресов строился маршрут.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
 var myMap,myPlacemark;
ymaps.ready(function() {     
    myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
        center: [54.989342, 73.368212],
        zoom: 16,
        controls: []
    });

    myMap.controls.add(
        new ymaps.control.ZoomControl()
    );

    myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark([54.989342, 73.368212], {
        hintContent: 'text'
    }, {
        iconLayout: 'default#image',
        iconImageHref: 'img/ya_marker.png',
        iconImageSize: [40, 48]
    });

    myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);
    myMap.behaviors.disable('scrollZoom');
     myMap.behaviors.disable('multiTouch');

});
```

Comment: А вы что то уже сделали? или с нуля вам все это надо?)))

Answer (score 1):

Пример создания транспортного маршрута на `yandex maps api`. Дополнительные описания в сомом коде по строкам:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script>
            ymaps.ready(init);

            function init() {
                var myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
                    center: [54.989342, 73.368212],
                    zoom: 13
                }, {
                    searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
                });
                //Добовляем точки для маршрута
                ymaps.route([
                    [54.989342, 73.368212], //Точька отправления (пункт а)
                    //здесь можно дать третий пункт, тогда маршрут будет проложен через пункт а к бункту б через этот пункт
                    [54.959342, 73.368212]  //Точька прибытия (пункт б)
                ]).then(function(route) {
                    myMap.geoObjects.add(route);
                    // Зададим содержание иконок начальной и конечной точкам маршрута.
                    // С помощью метода getWayPoints() получаем массив точек маршрута.
                    // Массив транзитных точек маршрута можно получить с помощью метода getViaPoints.
                    var points = route.getWayPoints(),
                            lastPoint = points.getLength() - 1;
                    // Задаем стиль метки - иконки будут красного цвета, и
                    // их изображения будут растягиваться под контент.
                    points.options.set('preset', 'islands#redStretchyIcon');
                    // Задаем контент меток в начальной и конечной точках.
                    points.get(0).properties.set('iconContent', 'Точка отправления');
                    points.get(lastPoint).properties.set('iconContent', 'Точка прибытия');

                    // Проанализируем маршрут по сегментам.
                    // Сегмент - участок маршрута, который нужно проехать до следующего
                    // изменения направления движения.
                    // Для того, чтобы получить сегменты маршрута, сначала необходимо получить
                    var moveList = 'Трогаемся,</br>',
                            way,
                            segments;
                    // Получаем массив путей.
                    for (var i = 0; i < route.getPaths().getLength(); i++) {
                        way = route.getPaths().get(i);
                        segments = way.getSegments();
                        for (var j = 0; j < segments.length; j++) {
                            var street = segments[j].getStreet();
                            moveList += ('Едем ' + segments[j].getHumanAction() + (street ? ' на ' + street : '') + ', проезжаем ' + segments[j].getLength() + ' м.,');
                            moveList += '</br>'
                        }
                    }
                    moveList += 'Останавливаемся.';
                    // Выводим маршрутный лист.
                    $('#list').append(moveList);
                }, function(error) {
                    alert('Возникла ошибка: ' + error.message);
                });
            }
        </script>
        <style>
            body, html {
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                font-family: Arial;
                font-size: 14px;
            }
            #list {
                padding: 10px;
            }
            #map {
                width: 100%; height: 300px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map"></div>
        <div id="list"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Подробно о создании маршрута с `yandex maps api` можете найти [тут](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/router).

Comment: спасибо. Но мне нужно чтобы окно с вводом начальной и конечной точки было активно

Comment: @Shebb А ты где то такое видел? кроме как на сайте яндекса?

Comment: Вот документация `https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.0/dg/concepts/router-docpage/` для создания маршрута, и такого нет там, другое дело поставить в ручную поля для задания точек и после с ново инициализировать карту, но это опять не то что вы хотели.

Answer (score 1):

Можете просто вывести Панель маршрутизации как элемента управления путем добавления в значение controls: (routeButtonControl )

```
function init() {
var map = new ymaps.Map('map', {
    center: [ymaps.geolocation.latitude, ymaps.geolocation.longitude],
    zoom: 11,
    controls: ['zoomControl','geolocationControl','routeButtonControl'],
```